# Google Kubernetes Engine Ingress TLS doesn't work

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

Using `gitlab` auto DevOps CI, it had set up `ingress` controller:

```
spec:
  rules:
  - host: api.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: production-auto-deploy
          servicePort: 5000
        path: /
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - api.example.com
    secretName: production-auto-deploy-tls
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

`http://api.example.com` works great, but `https://api.example.com` first gives me certificate error, and then after I add the exception I get `404` from Google Kubernetes Engine.

Why is the TLS certificate not configured right?

Why doesn't it direct the host to the service?

Load balancer

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
spec:
  clusterIP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - name: http
    nodePort: 30408
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  - name: https
    nodePort: 31101
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: https
  selector:
    app: nginx-ingress
    component: controller
release: ingress
```

sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Ingress

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
spec:
  clusterIP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  selector:
    app: nginx-ingress
    component: default-backend
    release: ingress
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP

status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Comment: What is your Ingress controller?

Comment: It's the yml I attached. What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Those are the ingress rules from your Kubernetes ingress resource. the Ingress is object is managed by an ingress controller which can be something like traefik or nginx

Comment: Ok I see this now. It actually just name port 80. Do I need to set there the certificate or just add https port and the controller handle everything else?

Comment: @itaied different features and annotation might be supported or not depending on choosen `Ingress` controller: ingress by kubernetes, Nginx, Traefik

Comment: Can you post what you see? It looks like it should be listening on port 443 already since you get a cert error on `https://api.example.com` otherwise you wouldn't get a response

Comment: Default controller on GKE GCLB

Comment: I have edited the question with more details. It's the default configuration from gitlab auto devops

Comment: I don't understand where you want do TLS negotiation, on LB or on Service?

Comment: I think it's better to be on the load balancer, so every service will have tls

Comment: Also In your example i see that you use nginx controller, not default GKE GCLB.
Have you install correctly nginx controller with tls certificate?

Comment: @itaied  in case you prefer tls negotiation on LB, you don't need listen 443 port on service.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, At the end i understand what you do.
You create NGINX service that that will balance over your services, as Ingress.
I don't understand  how NGINX service with CLUSTER_IP can be open to world and serve as ingress.

But here is plan what must be done to expose GKE service to WORLD.
1) configured service with clusterIp, that will be listen available inside k8s cluster
2) configured ingress rules.
3) In case you want use optional ingress controller on GKE, Install your controller.
Here is example how this may work on GCLB.(in case of GCLB, service must be exposed on NodePort, bad design)

service

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
  labels:
    app: service-nm
  name: service-name
  namespace: your-nm
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - nodePort: 30200
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 3001
  selector:
    app: operator
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort`

Igress

`apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: false
    ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert: np-ssl-certificate
spec:
  rules:
  - host: your domain-name
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: your-sn
          servicePort: 80
  - host: your-domain-name`

For more details how install nginx on GKE 
https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke